# Test case is showing as skipped in cucumber allure report, if the test failure happened at hooks level

Tags: cucumber-java, allure

We have set of codes need to be checked in hooks level, if it failed in hooks, we are looking for the report also should show as failed instead of **skipped**.

In hooks level, if scenario value has failed, tried to add below code to fail the test explicitly, but no luck ( i.e., always showing in report as skipped),

- throw new AssumptionViolatedException("Failed in hook level");
- Allure.step("Failed me", Status.BROKEN);
- Assert.assertTrue(false,"FAIL ME");